# tengo un problema al usar el metodo dispatch en mi vista basada en clases en django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

hola estoy realizando un proyecto con la ayuda de un curso de django 2 y cree un 'mixin' y y modifique el metodo dispatch de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me sale este error en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me sale esto en la terminal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he hecho exactamente lo que hace en el curso pero no me carga la pagina como a el, al parecer hay un problema al modificar el método dispatch si alguien me puede ayudar a resolverlo o tenga otra forma de hacer esto lo agradecería!!!

Answer (score 1):

Estas en lo correcto, el problema esta en el método dispatch ,en la linea #15 para ser mas exacto, le estas pasando 4 argumentos cuando deberian ser 3, trata cambiar ese codigo por este

```
return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```